# Manipulating Angular 2 route segments

Tags: angular, router

In my Angular 2 app I have a route 'addresses/:id' with some subroutes, e.g.

```
 - addresses/:id/detail 
 - addresses/:id/map 
 - addresses/:id/…
```

Starting from route

```
'addresses/123/map
```

I want to navigate to another address, e.g. id = 4711, but keep all the other segments:

```
addresses/4711/maps
```

Of course this is possible with some string manipulation but I am looking for a more elegant way.

Can I  replace only the id in the current route and use the result with the router.navigate(…) method?

Comment: Are you using child routes?

Comment: What do you mean by "more elegant way"?

Comment: Angular 2 is not very clever when it comes to routes. You can't even do simple regex in routing configuration... I read that more functionalities will be available but it's not the priority for now.

Comment: @Serginho, yes I am using child routes, addresses/:id is the parent and Details, map etc. are the children

Comment: @Roman C, with a "more elegant" way I mean something like (1) take the ActivatedRoute (2) replace the value of parmeter "id" (3) pass the result to the navigate method